# SASS: restrict a rule on tagname

Tags: sass, dry

Quite often I need to write something like:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-family: 'myfont';
  font-weight: normal;
  &.public {
    color: $white;
  }
}
```

But I'd like to add a specific rule to `h1.public` only. Of couse, I could add:

```
h1.public {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

but this is because my example is simple and still this is not really DRY. What I'd like is to have it wrapped in my code. Something like:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-family: 'myfont';
  font-weight: normal;
  &.public {
    color: $white;
    &:only(h1) {
      font-size: 2em;
    }
  }
}
```

Just like [media queries](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#media) work.

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have different possible approach:

[See in live](http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/f2666764e6d732b28c524f83fb4cb273)

```
/* Version 1: with @at-root */
h1 {
  @at-root &, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: 'myfont';
    font-weight: normal;
    &.public {
      color: #FFF;
    }
  }
  &.public {
    font-size: 2em;
  }
}

/* Version 2: with placeholders */
%org-heading {
  font-family: 'myfont';
  font-weight: normal;
  &.is-public {
    color: #FFF;
  }
}
@for $i from 1 to 6 {
  h#{$i} {
    @extend %org-heading;
    @if 1 == $i {
      &.is-public {
        font-size: 2em;
      }
    }
  }
}

/* Version 3: with modular approach */
.org-heading {
  font-family: 'myfont';
  font-weight: normal;
  &--public {
    color: #FFF;
    &.isFirst {
      font-size: 2em;
    }
  }
}
```